How to unit-test / mock code with beanie queries
So my concrete problem is that I am trying to create a unit test for something like this:
from mongo_models import Record

async def do_something(record_id: str):

    record = await Record.find_one(Record.id == record_id)

    if record is None:
        record = Record(id='randomly_generated_string', content='')

    # Other operations with `record` but we can ignore them for this

    return record


Where the mongo_models.py contains:
from beanie import Document

class Record(Document):
    id: str
    content: str


So I tried doing something like this:
import pytest

from core_code import do_something

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_do_something():
    """ Test do_something method."""

    # Create a mock for the object that will be returned by find_one
    record_mock = AsyncMock(spec=Record)
    record_mock.id = "test-id"
    record_mock.content = "Test content"

    # Test with the find_one method patched
    with patch('mongo_models.Record.find_one', return_value=record_mock) as mock_find_one:

        result = await do_something(record_id="input_id")

        # Assert that find_one was called
        mock_find_one.assert_awaited_once()

        # Assert the right object is being used
        assert result == record_mock


But I am getting an AttributeError: id error when is executed the instruction:
record = await Record.find_one(Record.id == record_id) line.

I think it gives an error is because you are trying to access a class attribute before the class is defined at Record.id, you can try to check if record exists before checking for equality with expected value.
record = await Record.find_one(Record.id == record_id)

Attached sample examples:
Code which will give error:
class test():
    id: str
    test: str
print(hasattr(test, 'id') -> will give False
print(test.id) -> will give AttributeError: type object 'test' has no attribute 'id'

Code which worked
class test():
    id = '1'
    test: str
print(hasattr(test, 'id')) -> gives True
print(test.id) -> gives '1'


I don't think this is the issue. The argument in record = await Record.find_one(Record.id == record_id) is not checking for equality (I cannot call this method using record = await Record.find_one(True), for example). This is just a syntax that beanie uses for querying the database for entries of Record which have id property equal to record_id (I have no idea how beanie manages to translate this in practice).

Then maybe for unit tests, this is just a python class and Record.id doesn't exist hence the error.
